On the wave function collapse
I'm particularly concerned with the conceptual consequences of this postulate, which I never quite pondered enough.

In quantum mechanics, wave function collapse, also called reduction of the state vector, occurs when a wave function — initially in a superposition of several ones — reduces to a single eigenstate due to interaction with the external world.

The problem is right here. Interactions with the external world happen constantly, and yet the wave function seems to just ignore them.
Take the good old Double Slit experiment for instance. Even in this simple case, there are a few unclear behaviours I can't explain to myself rationally.
Usually, such an experiment is performed in a dark environment. The reason for this, I believe, is just to see more clearly the interference pattern on the screen. But of course, the environment is not shielded completely, there is still some kind of radiation floating around, as long as the temperature is above absolute zero. The particle involved doesn't seem to care about it though. It's as if somehow it manages to distinguish, say, a photon of the background noise from that of a measuring device, and chooses to interact with the latter and not with the former.
Is there a minimum threshold below which any noise is just ignored? I don't believe so; otherwise the strength parameter $\lambda$ in perturbation theory shouldn’t be allowed to get arbitrarily close to $0$.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747477

There is a close vote for "needs more clarity". I disagree. However, it is likely a duplicate.

They closed it anyway, as I predicted.

You correctly pointed out that the solid obstacle with just two tiny slits ought to keep being collided by the incident particle flux. But that does not matter; the part of the particle flux that gets blocked by the incident particle flux does not change the wavefunction of the part that passes through the two slits, only in as much as the classical wave also changes due to how the slits interact with the wave.

Voting to reopen. The question might be rephrased like this - "In the double slit experiment, the wave function collapses when a photon hits the screen. This is how the interference pattern develops. Why doesn't an interaction with the environment collapse the wave function before hitting the screen. This should prevent the wave function from being created."

This Veritasium video might help - Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why

this is classic "over thinking". Learn to abstract.

@mmesser314 That is indeed the core question: why does this (supposed) collapse sometimes not occur? It is about the arbitrariness of "postulate physics". Perhaps OP can also edit the title to make it more focused among those lines.

Always add the source to a quote, in this case Penrose via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse . Note that already the third sentence in wikipedia, 'Collapse is one of the two processes by which quantum systems evolve in time; the other is the continuous evolution governed by the Schrödinger equation.', makes no sense as a collapse process does not exist.

It's probably worth pointing out that well written quantum mechanics textbooks don't use the term "wave function collapse" at all. I checked Sakurai a while ago. He doesn't use it for all I can tell. I don't remember seeing it in my old textbooks, either. It's not a useful concept. I don't even know where it comes from. Does anybody know the primary source for that meme?

Asher Peres (probably the most recent authority on this kind of stuff) does use “collapse” in his seminal “Quantum theory: concepts and methods.”  Kluwer academic publishers, 1997.  He has also written extensively on the topic.

A photon interacts with the environment when it hits an atom and is absorbed. Some aspects of this are not obvious. It does not always cause decoherence. For example in reflection, incoming photons are absorbed and new photons are emitted. In this case, the new photons the phase and wavelengths are related to the original (E.G. $180^o$ phase shift on reflection.)
This kind of interaction is not always with a single atom. A wave is reflected at the same angle to a surface as an incoming wave. It takes many atoms to define a surface. In a metal, conduction electrons are spread out across many atoms. It is the interaction with these electrons that cause the reflection. In a dielectric mirror, electrons are bound to atoms. It is the interaction with many atoms in multiple layers of the mirror that generate the reflection.
Transparent mediums also interact with the photons that pass through them. But they come out the other side with the same wavelength and a phase that can be calculated from the original. So the the double slit experiment can be carried out in air or have a window in it.
Photons are described by wave functions. They are spread out. When they pass though the slits, there is a chance they will be absorbed and a chance they will pass through. If they do pass through, the wave function on the other side is consistent with them having passed through. So even though they are not absorbed, they are affected.


Take the good old Double Slit experiment for instance. Even in this simple case, there are a few unclear behaviours I can't explain to myself rationally. Usually, such an experiment is performed in a dark environment. The reason for this, I believe, is just to see more clearly the interference pattern on the screen. But of course, the environment is not shielded completely, there is still some kind of radiation floating around, as long as the temperature is above absolute zero. The particle involved doesn't seem to care about it though. It's as if somehow it manages to distinguish, say, a photon of the background noise from that of a measuring device, and chooses to interact with the latter and not with the former.

Quantum theory has specific equations of motion such as the Schrodinger equation that aren't compatible with collapse.
There are alternatives to quantum theory that feature collapse:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
but those theories don't currently reproduce the predictions of relativistic quantum theories and so don't account for the vast bulk of experimental results predicted using quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
In unmodified quantum theory when information about a measured system is copied out of the system that interaction suppresses interference: this effect is called decoherence. If an interaction with a system is weak enough then it acts a bit like a small but non-zero probability of preventing interference. This tends to diminish the interference without completely eliminating it. This effect has been observed in real experiments: see section 6 of Schlosshauer's review on decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
So in both theory and practice a particle will care about the environment to the extent that the environment copies information out of the particle.

It's not "information" that is "copied out of the system". It's energy. Every measurement process removes energy from or adds energy to the system under measurement. I don't know when physicists stopped using the term energy for processes that are all about energy transfer between systems, but it is extremely concerning. We try very hard to teach kids at the high school level all about energy and then, when it comes to an actual application of that term, we suddenly switch over to "information". To me that makes very little sense.

@FlatterMann It is information that's copied out of the system. Decoherence can take place without energy transfer https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6750
https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.14216

Even that system has an interaction Hamiltonian, i.e. some form of system property change has taken place. Show me an example where H_SB=0 and then I believe  the information magic, although even that would be tentative because as we know, information requires energy in a physical world of finite temperatures.

We first have to note that:

Our current best theory for quantum behavior is quantum field theory (QFT). In that theory the state of a system sometimes acts like a wave, but never like a classical point particle.
In addition, the collapse of the quantum state is not incorporated in QFT, it is just a postulate that some people believe in. There never has been a widely accepted theory in which it actually happens, all such
["objective collapse theories"]
are plagued by inconsistencies, like violating energy conservation or relativistic invariance.
There is no compelling reason to insist that there has to be a collapse (as it once was), since nowadays we know that
[einselection]  can describe an apparent collapse, where in reality the superposition of many states simply remains in existence.

Still your questions about the double-slit experiment can then be translated to: Why does the EM quantum field act like a wave when light passes through a double slitted screen? And
why does einselection lead to the observed result, i.e. the dots on the photographic plate with the pattern of dark and light fringes?
These questions are difficult to answer since QFT is a difficult theory as soon as more than a few particles are involved. If you look at the links I gave, you'll quickly find out that you have to delve into a lot of mathematics an fundamental physics to find out more.
And strangely, questions like this are always downvoted and quickly closed on physics SE. I do not understand why, but anyhow I'll quickly post this (admittedly incomplete) answer before closing occurs!

If you do not understand why "questions like this are always downvoted and quickly closed," please review this help page: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

OP asked three questions: "Is there a minimum threshold below which any noise is just ignored? ...Shouldn't the mere presence of an obstacle induce (almost always) the collapse? How come the particle traverses it quietly, through the slits, with no odd effects like quantum tunnelling or something, just some interference, and gets irrefutably perturbed at the second and last screen?" Which of those do you think is a clear answerable question?

I'm not sure your argument is correct. QFT is still going to be subjected to interpretation hell; the computational difficulties of QFT should be orthogonal to these interpretation issues.

Also, this does not seem to answer the question. Ultimately your "answer" seems to just be the statement: "These questions are difficult to answer..."

@hft I agree. This is commentary and answers none of the 3 questions asked.

I still think it is a good beginning of an answer (and I had to be quick to get it in of course!) All the critical remarks prove to me how afraid physicists are to really address the questions about collapse.
